# How to do a Generalized Complex Schur (or QZ) Decomposition with Eigen C++?

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, eigensystem, lapack, eigen

I would like to do a Generalized Schur (or QZ) decomposition for a pair of complex matrices $A$ and $B$.

I found the following class:

```
class Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<_MatrixType>
```

but it seems that it only works for real matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking for alternative software packages, or whether Eigen can do that?

Comment: Can Eigen do that?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm asking what exactly you are asking in your original question.

Comment: Do you know alternative software packages?

Comment: No, I don't, actually. It's not my field :-)

Answer (score 1):

Numerical computation of Generalized Complex Schur decomposition can be performed by calling *zgges*() LAPACK function.
For example, see [NETLIB zgees](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/zgges.f.html) documentation, or a documentation for any other BLAS/LAPACK library implementation.

Eigen is technically nothing else, but a very convenient templated library of wrappers and algorithms, also including some custom implementation. However, for maximum Eigen performance, it is recommended to link it to a LAPACK\BLAS library, for example, Intel MKL.

Now, regarding Schur decomposition in Eigen. I have not used the functionality from [GeneralizedEigenSolver](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html), but according to the documentation, only real matrices are supported. 
The following code compiles correctly:

```
Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> solver;
Eigen::MatrixXf A(4,4),B(4,4);
solver.compute(A,B);
```

However, the complex version results in a compilation error that pretty much describes itself: no support for complex matrices yet:

```
Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXcd> solver;
Eigen::MatrixXcd A(4,4),B(4,4);
solver.compute(A,B);

Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/GeneralizedEigenSolver.h:367:20: error: no viable conversion from 'CoeffReturnType' (aka 'const std::__1::complex<double>') to 'RealScalar' (aka 'double')
```

The example is tested on Eigen 3.3.4.
So, I would suggest you to use LAPACK function directly (you have to have some BLAS\LAPACK library connected to your code) without using Eigen wrappers for now.